# C# slow when Load Form UI while adding table row

Tags: .net, performance, datagridview

Maybe my codes little bit complicated but the point is, there's a lag/UI flickering when i'm trying to make some Textboxs visible while filling my table using initializeForm(). [Here an example, see the input form(left-side)](https://ibb.co/iFdAey)
.I know it's because of initializeTbl() that run so slow. So i put it on the second line, but somehow it was executed at the sametime with clearInput(0) or in other words before clearInput(0) done.

i've tried using doublebuffered, and Turn on WS_EX_COMPOSITED(no flickering, but delay about 2 seconds)

```
public void initializeForm()
        {
            clearInput(0); //Refresh input form, and make all Textbox visible
            initializeTbl(); //Clear and Filling table's Row
        }   

//RESET INPUT PANEL(TO EMPTY) 
public void clearInput(int mode)
        {
            if (this.mode == 0 || mode == 0)
            {
                editKategoriBtn.Visible = false;
                editSatuanBtn.Visible = false;
            }
            this.mode = mode;

            //RESET UI
            if (mode == 0)
                modeInsert();
            else if (mode == 1)
                modeUpdate();

            //REMOVE SATUAN FORM
            persatuanTb.Visible = false;
            satuanLine.Visible = false;


            //RESET FORM TEXT
            satuanDd.Clear();
            kategoriDd.Clear();
            setDDKategori();
            setDDSatuan();

            selectedSatuan = -1;

            idBrgTb.Text = "ID Barang";
            namaBrgTb.Text = "Nama Barang";
            stokBrgTb.Text = "Jumlah Stok";
            persatuanTb.Text = "Satuan(PCS)";
            hargaBeliTb.Text = "Harga Beli";

            setLineColor();

            //RESET VARIABLE
            barangID = "";
            barangName = "";
            checkHargaJual = false;

            //RESET ARRAY
            arrayGrosir = new List<List<WindowsFormsControlLibrary1.BunifuCustomTextbox>> { };
            arrayQty = new List<List<WindowsFormsControlLibrary1.BunifuCustomTextbox>> { };

            arraySatuanHJ = new List<String> { };
            arrayJmlSatuan = new List<String> { };
            arrayHj = new List<LinkLabel> { };

            //RESET HARGA JUAL LINKLABEL
            hjPanel.Controls.Clear();
        }

public void initializeTbl() 
        {
            String id_trans = String.Empty;
            if (tabelBarang.Rows.Count != 0)
            {
                id_trans = Convert.ToString(tabelBarang.SelectedRows[0].Cells["id_brg"].Value);
            }

            int curBaris = tabelBarang.RowCount;

            String filter = "";
            if (searchTb.Text.Count() >= 3 && searchTb.Text != "Cari Barang")
            {
                filter = "AND (tb_barang.id_brg Like '%" + searchTb.Text + "%' OR tb_barang.nama_brg Like '%" + searchTb.Text + "%') ";
            }

            String query = "SELECT DISTINCT id_brg,nama_brg,ctg_name,nama_satuan,convert(DOUBLE PRECISION, jml_satuan) as jml_satuan,convert(DOUBLE PRECISION, stock) as stock FROM " +
                "tb_barang,tb_category,tb_satuan WHERE " +
                "tb_barang.id_kategori=tb_category.ctg_id AND tb_barang.id_satuan=tb_satuan.id_satuan " + filter +
                "ORDER BY stock";

            int newBaris = db.getRowNumber(query);
            if (curBaris != newBaris || searchTb.Text == "Cari Barang")
            {

                if (tabelBarang.Rows.Count != 0)
                    clearTable();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, db.sqlcon);
                using (SqlDataReader read = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    object[] tbBarang;
                    while (read.Read())
                    {
                        object id_brg = read.GetValue(read.GetOrdinal("id_brg"));
                        object nama_brg = read.GetValue(read.GetOrdinal("nama_brg"));
                        object ctg_name = read.GetValue(read.GetOrdinal("ctg_name"));
                        object nama_satuan = read.GetValue(read.GetOrdinal("nama_satuan"));
                        object jml_satuan = read.GetValue(read.GetOrdinal("jml_satuan"));
                        object stock = read.GetValue(read.GetOrdinal("stock"));
                        if (nama_satuan.ToString() != "PCS" && nama_satuan.ToString() != "KG")
                        {
                            jml_satuan += " PCS/" + nama_satuan;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            jml_satuan += " " + nama_satuan;
                        }


                        if (nama_satuan.ToString() != "KG")
                            stock += " PCS";
                        else
                            stock += " KG";
                        tabelBarang.Rows.Add(tbBarang = new object[] { id_brg, nama_brg, ctg_name, nama_satuan, jml_satuan, stock });
                    }
                }
            }
            if (selectRow(0, id_trans))
            {
                tabelBarang.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = tabelBarang.SelectedRows[0].Index;
                tabelBarang.PerformLayout();
            }
        }

//SET INPUT FORM TO INSERT MODE
private void modeInsert()
        {
            submitBtn.Text = "TAMBAH BARANG";
            submitBtn.BackColor = Color.Gray;

            searchTb.Text = "Cari Barang";

            stockBrgLbl.Text = "Jumlah Stok";

            satuanBrgLbl.Visible = true;
            satuanBarangPanel.Visible = true;
            //satuanBarangPanel.Enabled = true;

            hargaBeliLbl.Visible = true;
            hargaBeliPnl.Visible = true;
            //hargaBeliPnl.Enabled = true;

            stockBrgLbl.Visible = true;
            stokBarangPnl.Visible = true;
            //stokBarangPnl.Enabled = true;

            persatuanTb.Enabled = true;
        }

//SET INPUT FORM TO UPDATE MODE
private void modeUpdate()
        {
            submitBtn.Text = "UPDATE BARANG";
            submitBtn.BackColor = Color.Orange;

            hargaBeliLbl.Visible = false;
            hargaBeliPnl.Visible = false;

            satuanBrgLbl.Visible = false;
            satuanBarangPanel.Visible = false;

            stockBrgLbl.Visible = false;
            stokBarangPnl.Visible = false;

            persatuanTb.Visible = false;
        }
```

Comment: The easiest way: use `SqlDataReader.ReadAsync` method instead of `Read`.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, not the easiest if you have existing code. If you start using it, async-await will spread over whole codebase, which will force you to make bigger change, then just one function.

Comment: _but somehow it was executed before clearInput(0) done_ - it is not possible. `ClearInput(0)` will be executed before `initializeTbl()`, unless you have some other handlers which executes `initializeTbl()`.

Comment: In your application try to search for `'; DELETE FROM tb_barang; --`